# git client which can do a directory diff

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-extensions, gitk, smartgit

I know that the latest git can use this command to **directory** diff two versions:

`git difftool -d <sha1> <sha1>`

But I can't find any git clients(**GUI**) which can do this job.

I've tried
`tortoisegit`
`smartgit`
`git-cola`
`git-extentions`
`github`
`gitk`

None of them has this feature, could anyone recommend any git client(runs on windows xp) which can do this?

I don't know if `sourcetree` can do this or not, cause I don't have either win7 or mac.

Thanks.

Comment: You don’t know what to set as difftool?

Comment: I know how to set a difftool, and I also know how to directory diff two revisions via command line, I just don't know what git client (GUI) can do this simply by selecting two revisions and click some "directory diff these two revisions"

Answer (score 1):

The standard windows git client, [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), can do this if you configure it to use [Beyond Compare 3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) (not free) as diff tool.

You can set it up [like this](http://theo.im/blog/2012/10/27/directory-comparison-for-git-difftool/):

```
git config --global diff.tool bc3
git config --global difftool.bc3.cmd "\"c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Edit:
Actually kdiff3 does this too, and is free. [Setup here](http://www.gitshah.com/2010/12/how-to-setup-kdiff-as-diff-tool-for-git.html):

```
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3

[merge]
    tool = kdiff3

[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/YourPathToBinaryHere/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false

[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/YourPathToBinaryHere/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
```

Comment: I know how to do this through a command line, but what I want is a GUI which can simply select two revisions and click a `directory diff these two versions` or something like that. Not entering the `git difftool -d rev1 rev2`

Answer (score 1):

in tortoise git:

- open "git log"
- mark two commits
- rightclick
- compare these revisions

Comment: Hold down shift before and during right clicking for "Show Reflog". This lets you compare local and remote versions. I use it to see what exactly my branch is trying to do for example.

Answer (score 0):

In SmartGit/Hg you can configure external file compare tools: go to **Edit|Preferences** and configure them at **Tools** - **File Comparators**.

You can diff two commits from within the Log: just select both of them in the **Graph** view (Control-click on Windows) and you will see all changes in the **Files** view. Here you can investigate individual files with your external compare tool simply by double-clicking.

Comment: But how to do a directory diff? not viewing a diff of single files each time.

Comment: Why would you like to do that in an external tool? A Git client will do the directory diff more efficiently.

Comment: Because you can't persuade all your colleges to us the command line interface, and that feature is what they get used to because of `tortoisehg`

Comment: @shengy Maybe I misunderstood your goal -- I've added more information to my answer.

Comment: Thats not my goal either:), you can update your git to the latest version and setup a difftool like `beyond compare` or `kdiff3` or `meld` and then use the command `git difftool -d rev1 rev2` and see the effects, my goal is to finish this job in a GUI by a few clicks without involving any command line input.

Comment: I see now. There is no such option to do that with SmartGit/Hg. SmartGit/Hg has its own built-in "Files" area which is more or less a directory diff view.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use gitk. Right click on a commit -> `mark this commit`. Right click on another commit -> `diff this -> marked commit`.

Comment: This also does not do a directory diff, I can only view single files in my difftool once a time by right clicking the file and select `external diff`

Comment: where did I say anything about an external diff? Gitk itself will diff all the files in your worktree.

Comment: I know the work is done by git, but the real thing is my colleges are used to see the side-by-side diff, not the united diff.